# Kendo Grid, how to translate bottom toolbar (count of pages, etc)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, translation

I would like to translate bottom toolbar in Kendo Grid component (count of pages, items per page,etc..), see image below.

[image]

I know how to translate column filter, but i don't know how exactly I can translate bottom toolbar.

Many Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change paging messages via grid pageable messages options:

```
pageable: {
    pageSize: 2,
    messages: {
        display: "Showing {0}-{1} from {2} data items",
        itemsPerPage: "data items per page"

    }
}
```